# Php override construction error in extends controller mvc structure

Tags: php

In php mvc structure I have this base controller class and add the constructor like this :

```
namespace App\Core;
/**
* Controller class
*/

class Controller
{
    /** @var View View The view object */
    public $View;
    public $templates;
    public $app;
    /**
     * Construct the (base) controller. This happens when a real controller is constructed, like in
     * the constructor of IndexController when it says: parent::__construct();
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->app = \App\Core\System\App::instance();
        $this->Language = new Language('en-gb');
        $this->templates = new \League\Plates\Engine(Config::get('PATH_VIEW'));
        $this->Url = new \App\Core\Url(Config::get('URL'),Config::get('URL'));
    }

    public function loadModel($name) {

        $path = '\App\Catalog\Model\\'.$name;

        $this->model = new $path;

        return $this->model;

    }

    public function loadController($name) {

        $path = '\App\Catalog\Controller\\'.$name;

        $this->controller = new $path;

        return $this->controller;

    }
}
```

Now in action (ie edit account) controller i have :

```
namespace App\Catalog\Controller\Account;
use App\Core\Config;
use App\Core\Csrf;
use App\Core\Response;
use App\Core\Session;

class EditAccount extends \App\Core\Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        //Auth::checkAuthentication();
    }
    public function index()
    {
    }
    public function action()
    {
    }
}
```

Now, I work in PhpStorm and see this `override` error:

[image]

How do can in Fix this error?

Note: If I remove `extends \App\Core\Controller` from `EditAccount` class, error fixed But I need to `extends \App\Core\Controller`.

Comment: This is not an error, but is a notice. PHPStorm tells you that there is also a original constructor. Nothing to worry about.
If you're using OOP than you can override methods of parent classes. That's how it suppose to be.